# keyboard of first ViewController's textfield appears in next ViewController for some seconds

Tags: objective-c, ios8, keyboard, uitextfield, xcode6.4

I am developing app in Xcode 6.4 and running in simulator and device of iOS 8.0 and above. I have a textfield in a view controller and its value is passed to next view controller.

as usual `nextscreen.str = textfield.text;`

The problem is that a keyboard of that textfield is appear in next screen for some seconds after pushing to that ViewController. I have also write `[textField resignFirstResponder];`

All other thing are working fine and app is ready to upload on store. But this problem should not be there. The keyboard should not to be seen in next screen, if it is then it is a bug in UI of project that will affect to my work. Please help if any have solution of this. I am seeing this first time. And applied all possible known ways but no result found for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Edit : I have put an alert view and on click of alert view's button, I have push to next view. Then also that problem is there.

Answer (score 1):

while next viewcontroller will appear

in

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: What is this and how does it answer the question?

Comment: its hide keyboard forcefully

Comment: what code I have to put for this problem? [textField resignFirstResponder]; or of pushviewcontroller? Is there any need code like this?

Comment: On next viewcontroller viewwillappear method put the above code @Max

Answer (score 0):

First hide keyboard  then push Viewcontroller i had solved this issue

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
// write you push code or Segue code
```

Comment: As I mentioned in question that I have already hide keyboard by resignFirstResponder.

Comment: check  in next view controller  becomeFirstResponder will be  call

Comment: becomeFirstResponder of textfield is for that view controller only, how it becomeFirstResponder in another view controller. without delegate

Comment: try to push next viewcontroller after some delay so that keyboard hide completely then next viewcontroller appear

Comment: I have given delay then also same issue.